# How can i stop Eclipse's "Servers" tab from grabbing focus when start/stopping a server?

Tags: eclipse

When using Eclipse IDE, anytime the server (tomcat in my case) changes status (start, starting, stopping, stopped, etc...), the Servers tab becomes active. This is annoying because then I can't see Console.

By default, I think Console has "Show Console when std out/err changes" which results in a minor skirmish between the two tabs. I don't like having this option either. I simply want the tab I chose to stay active, none of the auto business.

Is there any way to stop Servers tab from grabbing focus/active?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I should mention that my Console and Servers tab live in the same grouping of tabs.

Answer (score 95):

You can disable the focus grabbing in **Preferences - Server**. There is a single Checkbox "Show Servers view when server state changes".

Also:

Preferences -> Rund/Debug -> Console:
Disable "Show console when standard output changes"

Comment: There really needs to be a way for moderators to select the correct answer for people who just don't pay attention.

Comment: This does not seem to work in Eclipse Mars. I deselected both options and still my servers view gets focus whenever I change a resource file of an application published on this server.

Comment: That's a bummer, @vap78. It's working for me in Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1). I made sure the server wasn't running, unchecked the "Show Servers view when server state changes" checkbox, then restarted Eclipse and it did the trick.

Comment: Not working for me. Mars 4.5.2 on Mac OS. I stopped server, unchecked the box, restarted Eclipse, restarted server... clicked a different view and server grabbed focus right away.

Comment: This works for me: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200

Answer (score 5):

To prevent this, deselect these options:

[image: screenshot]

> "Show console when standard output changes"

and

> "Show console when standard error changes"

Then the console will not take focus.

But what I advise is to use the simple short cuts for navigation:

> ```
> Press F12 to return to Editor. 
>
> Press Alt+Shift+Q, P  - to return to the package editor 
> Press Alt+Shift+Q, O  - to outline
> Press Alt+Shift+Q, S  - to search
> Press Alt+Shift+Q, C  - to console
> Press Alt+Shift+Q, Q  - to show all views and choose correct 
>
> Press Ctrl+F7 - display a list of opened views
> Press Ctrl+F8 - select perspective
> ```

Comment: I've already done this, but servers tab still grabs focus away.

Comment: The servers and the console view are two different things in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Preferences -> Rund/Debug -> Console:

Disable "Show console when standard output changes"

Comment: The servers and the console view are two different things in Eclipse.