# Automatically switch Debug and Variable/Expression views in MyEclipse Workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I'm beginner in `MyEclispe Workbech`. When I run my application in `debug` mood, `Debug` view will enable automatically and I enable manually `Expression` view and when I press <kbd>F6</kbd> key(`Step Over` key) or <kbd>F5</kbd> then `Debug` view enable again automatically.

I want active `Expression` view and don't automatically changes.

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am learning english language.)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the menu on Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Perspectives and select whether you want it to prompt you for the Debug view or Always use it or Never use it.

Comment: My means isn't `Perspectives` configuration, I want deactivate automatically switch between `views` .

Comment: Sorry then I guess this is your only choice if possible:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685199/how-can-i-stop-eclipses-servers-tab-from-grabbing-focus-when-start-stopping-a

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for solve this issue. I do following steps:

1. `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Run/Debug
2. Do check or unchecked `Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit` checkbox.

By this solution my requirments solved.