# Eclipse server tab grabs focus on save

Tags: javascript, eclipse, server, tomcat7, eclipse-mars

I recently installed Eclipse Mars and I have a Tomcat 7 server running. I am developing JavaScript and editing HTML. Whenever I save my changes, the changes are getting automatically republished to the server directory. My issue now is, that the Server tab grabs the focus after this republishing so I always need to click back to the editor to get my focus back for further editing.

I was using Eclipse Luna and did never experience that issue.

I tried the solution provided in 
[How can i stop Eclipse's "Servers" tab from grabbing focus when start/stopping a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685199/how-can-i-stop-eclipses-servers-tab-from-grabbing-focus-when-start-stopping-a)
bit it did not help in my case.

Anyone has another idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. In the server tab, open up the little drop down when clicking on the "arrow down" symbol. Then select "Customize view". In the new dialog, open the Content tab and disable "Server Logs". This helped in my case and the focus is no more lost in the edit window when the server is doing a publish.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to double click on "Tomcat v7.0 Server" in the server perspective and click on the "Publishing" tab and select the "Never publish automatically" radio button as you are working in HTML and JS as the browser will automatically take your HTML changes. 
The other is close the server perspective and continue your coding so it will not focus on the server perspective when you are working.

Comment: Our build engine is publishing also JS code and HTML to the release directories on any change, therefore your first idea wont help. To not use the server tab is of course an option, but it is not that nice as for any server operations (e.g. restart) you would need to get the tab first back open.

Comment: what kind of application is it?
which build engine you are using